# Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $-1 \lt x \le1$. Is the convergence uniform?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $-1 \lt x \le1$. Is the convergence uniform?

To show that it is not uniformly convergent, is it enough to say that
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,& -1<x<1 \\[2ex]
1,& x=1
\end{cases}
 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: it is enough to note that the pointwise limit of $f_n$ fails to be continuous.  In particular, you are applying the contrapositive of the statement "if $f_n \to f$ uniformly with each $f_n$ continuous, then $f$ must also be continuous".